# The multi_vowel_words function returns all words with 3 or more consecutive vowels

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re
    def multi_vowel_words(text):
        pattern =r"\b\w[aeiou]{3,},?\s?.*\w[aeiou]{3,}.*\b"
        result = re.findall(pattern, text)
        return result
```

Where I am doing wrong

After running my code I'm getting this:

```
[]
['queen is courageous and gracious']
['quietly and await their delicious dinner']
[]
[]

#below this are desired outputs
print(multi_vowel_words("Life is beautiful")) 
# ['beautiful']

print(multi_vowel_words("Obviously, the queen is courageous and 
gracious.")) 

# ['Obviously', 'queen', 'courageous', 'gracious']

print(multi_vowel_words("The rambunctious children had to sit quietly and 
await their delicious 
dinner.")) 
# ['rambunctious', 'quietly', 'delicious']

print(multi_vowel_words("The order of a data queue is First In First Out 
(FIFO)")) 
   # ['queue']

print(multi_vowel_words("Hello world!")) 
   # []
print(multi_vowel_words("The order of a data queue is First In First Out 

(FIFO)")) # ['queue']

print(multi_vowel_words("Hello world!")) # []
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: where my pattern is going wrong??

Comment: What are you trying to do? Throw some text in the code

Comment: Your pattern is matching strings that begin with a word containing 3 consecutive vowels and **end** with **another** such word. I guess that's not what you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to take a stab at answering this question. How about a simple pattern to check for three consecutive vowels

```
def multi_vowel_words(text):
    pattern =r"\b\w*[aeiou]{3,}\w*\b"
    result = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return result
```

Comment: Will not match `Obviously`…

Comment: r"\b\w*[aeiou]{1}[aeiou]{1}[aeiou]{1}\w*\b" this is also working

Comment: Yeah you can replace `[A-Za-z]`->`\w`

Comment: Will not match [`Aeolian`](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aeolian) – for an obvious reason.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone is using `\w` to match the preceding and ending characters of vowels. That's wrong as `\w` matches any single letter, number or underscore (same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ). The correct pattern should be :

```
pattern = r"\b[A-Za-z]*[aeiou]{3,}[A-Za-z]*\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = r"\w*[aeiou]{3,}\w*"
```

This will work.

Comment: Please add some explanation and link to official documentation to your answer such that others can learn from it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: pattern = r"\w+[aeiou]{3,}\w*" works correctly . \w+ adds before and \w* adds the reaming part of word .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I guessed your intent correctly, this is the regexp you need:

```
r"\b\w*[aeiou]{3,}\w*\b"
```